# Connect Android Studio with android via AirDroid

Tags: android, android-studio

My computer seems to be too slow to run the android studio emulator (it wanted me to install some hardware acceleration), so I can't test apps there. Also my USB Cord doesn't work, I am wondering if it is possible to test apps in Android Studio via airdroid(http://web.airdroid.com/). I'm not sure how to set this up, however, since I don't really know how to configure android Studio to get this to work: as android studio only seems to work via a USB connection (which is not working for me). To sum it all up: I want to test apps on my phone via airdroid from android studio, and I need to know how to configure this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, AirDroid doesn't support ADB. But if really don't have a USB, you can use some Apps like WiFi ADB to get ADB work over WiFi

But if you are accidently using CyanogenMod or any other Mods which have  **ADB over Network**, it could be natively supported

[image: CyanogenMod's ADB over Network]

Comment: I don't have that option in my debugging section of developer options. I have USB debugging, Revoke USB devugging..., power menu bug reports, allow mock locations, select debug app, wait for debugger(greyed out), select debug app, wait for debugger(also greyed out), verify apps of usb, and wirelss display cerfication

Comment: @Kemosabe Sorry my bad, it's only an option provided by CyanogenMod or any other Mods. Try [WiFi ADB ](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en). It should also work! But obviously root needed.

Answer (score 0):

Download e.g. Shell Terminal Emulator (on Google Play). Open it and run

> adb tcpip 5555

Open the terminal in Android Studio and write

> adb connect ip_to_android_phone:5555

OBS!
*Some devices require root access, while others don't.*

Comment: This doesn't work, since I don't have a functioning USB cable, as mentioned in the original post.